# Displaying retrieved contents of an of epub file that displays in html Form in Flutter

Tags: flutter, epub

I was able to actually retrieve the contents of an ebup file 'https://pub.dev/packages/epub_parser' out using a simple package but it returns a html content instead, please how can i processed this contents and be able to show it on a widget like text or flip widget? here is my code

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:epub_parser/epub_parser.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BookTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const BookTest({super.key, required this.book});
  final File? book;

  @override
  State<BookTest> createState() => _BookTestState();
}

class _BookTestState extends State<BookTest> {
  late EpubBook _book;
  late Future<void> _loadBook;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadBook = _loadEpubBook();
  }

  Future<void> _loadEpubBook() async {
    // String fileName = 'assets/files/rich.epub';
    // String fullPath = p.join(Directory.current.path, fileName);
    File file = File(widget.book!.path);
    List<int> bytes = await file.readAsBytes();
    _book = await EpubReader.readBook(bytes);
    print('bytes');
    print(_book);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _loadBook,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  for (EpubChapter chapter in _book.Chapters!) ...[
                    Text(
                      chapter.Title!,
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Text(chapter.HtmlContent!),
                  ],
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i was able to read them, but it shows me the content in a html format, please is there anyone that knows how i can display them very well and legible for a normal reader, here is how it looks on simulator

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use flutter_html package

here is the sample code:

```
    Html(
        data: htmlData.outerHtml,
        onLinkTap: (href, _, __) => onExternalLinkPressed(href!),
        style: {
          'html': Style(
            padding: HtmlPaddings.only(
              top: (options.paragraphPadding as EdgeInsets?)?.top,
              right: (options.paragraphPadding as EdgeInsets?)?.right,
              bottom: (options.paragraphPadding as EdgeInsets?)?.bottom,
              left: (options.paragraphPadding as EdgeInsets?)?.left,
            ),
          ).merge(Style.fromTextStyle(options.textStyle)),
        },
        extensions: [
          TagExtension(
            tagsToExtend: {"img"},
            builder: (imageContext) {
              final url =
                  imageContext.attributes['src']!.replaceAll('../', '');
              final content = Uint8List.fromList(
                  document.Content!.Images![url]!.Content!);
              return Image(
                image: MemoryImage(content),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
```